# Pass function of an object to another object

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I want to pass function of one object to another function as an argument. Below code is only for indication of the problem, (not realistic code). How can function IdNeeded can take function getNextId of class Bar?

```
class Foo
{
public:
   void IdNeeded(getNextId);
}

class Bar
{
public:
   int getNextId()
   {
      return ++id;
   }
private:
   int id = 0;
}

int main()
{
    Bar bar;
    Foo foo;
    foo.IdNeeded(bar.getNextId); // foo will get id = 1

    Foo anotherFoo;
    anotherFoo.IdNeeded(bar.getNextId); // anotherFoo will get id = 2, because "id" is already incremented by one for foo object
}
```

I tried to use std::function, function pointer, std::bind, but unfortunately could not reach a final solution.

Comment: `Foo` doesn't have method `getNextId`, nor does `Bar` have a method `IdNeeded`. Please provide [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Provide a proper call back definition, and use a lambda to pack your object `Foo`:

```
#include <functional>

class Foo
{
public:
   void IdNeeded(std::function<int()> f){ f();}
};

class Bar
{
public:
   int getNextId()
   {
      return ++id;
   }
private:
   int id = 0;
};

int main()
{
    Bar bar;
    Foo foo;
    foo.IdNeeded([&](){return bar.getNextId();}); // foo will get id = 1
}
```